# OpenGL redefinition error while compiling glm conflict with Windows SDK files

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, redefinition

When I add a module(using `OpenGL` and `glm`) (which tested and compiled OK as a single program) into a big program. errors happened when compiling the glm in the project:

```
1>d:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\glm\core\type_gentype.hpp(48) : error C2332: “class”: missing tag name
1>d:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\glm\core\type_gentype.hpp(48) : error C2011: “<unnamed-tag>”: “enum” type redefinition
1>        c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\shlobj.h(3599) : see declaration of '<unnamed-tag>'
```

I searched google and found a similar problem at [here](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?406674-Template-problems-while-porting-to-VC8.). the answer said it has something wrong with the header file sequence, but I don't know how to fix it.

the code in the `type_gentype.hpp`, the code is in the [glm](http://glm.g-truc.net/).

```
namespace glm
{
    enum profile
    {
        nice,
        fast,
        simd
    };

namespace detail
{
    template
    <
        typename VALTYPE, 
        template <typename> class TYPE   //**The error indicator pointing at here**
    >
    struct genType
    {
    public:
        enum ctor{null};

        typedef VALTYPE value_type;
        typedef VALTYPE & value_reference;
        typedef VALTYPE * value_pointer;
        typedef VALTYPE const * value_const_pointer;
        typedef TYPE<bool> bool_type;

        typedef sizeType size_type;
        static bool is_vector();
        static bool is_matrix();

        typedef TYPE<VALTYPE> type;
        typedef TYPE<VALTYPE> * pointer;
        typedef TYPE<VALTYPE> const * const_pointer;
        typedef TYPE<VALTYPE> const * const const_pointer_const;
        typedef TYPE<VALTYPE> * const pointer_const;
        typedef TYPE<VALTYPE> & reference;
        typedef TYPE<VALTYPE> const & const_reference;
        typedef TYPE<VALTYPE> const & param_type;

        //////////////////////////////////////
        // Address (Implementation details)

        value_const_pointer value_address() const{return value_pointer(this);}
        value_pointer value_address(){return value_pointer(this);}

    //protected:
    //  enum kind
    //  {
    //      GEN_TYPE,
    //      VEC_TYPE,
    //      MAT_TYPE
    //  };

    //  typedef typename TYPE::kind kind;
    };

    template
    <
        typename VALTYPE, 
        template <typename> class TYPE
    >
    bool genType<VALTYPE, TYPE>::is_vector()
    {
        return true;
    }
```

The redefinition part of the `enum` in the `c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\shlobj.h(3599)`

```
enum
{   // **The error indicator pointing at here**
    BMICON_LARGE = 0,
    BMICON_SMALL
};

#undef  INTERFACE
#define INTERFACE   IBanneredBar
// the rest of the shlobj.h file
```

Comment: Could you provide the code where the problem appears? Maybe forgotten semicolon, or something duplicated in the process of splitting up into separate files?

Comment: @RandolphCarter I add the code the error indicator pointing at

Comment: shouldn't it be `template <typename blah> class TYPE` (you're missing the template parameter name)

Comment: and BMICON_LARGE sounds like a predefined constant from windows; if you absolutely need to redeclare an enum value with that name, put it into a separate namespace

Comment: problem solved. in the big program, someone using the `#define short TYPE` which conflict with the `TYPE` in the `type_gentype.hpp`

Answer (score 1):

Regarding BMICON_LARGE, this sounds like there is already a predefined constant / enum value by that name. The best solution would be to simply use a different name. If you absolutely need to have that exact name, put it into your own namespace; or you could maybe use the already defined value.